# Can I use the Hasura quickstart for production?

Tags: docker, heroku, graphql, hasura

I have just started to use Hasura and I wanted to know. Do I have to use the deployment methods for a simple app or can I just use the quickstart on Heroku/Docker, Download the Hasura CLI and continue from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with that, but there are a number of tweaks you'd want to make if you're going to use it in production.  They have a checklist that can walk you through them here:

https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/deployment/production-checklist.html

Comment: So I can start a adjust later by this list?

Comment: At minimum I would ensure that HTTPS is on and you've set an admin secret. Otherwise your console is exposed to anyone who knows the url!